# Swift Combine completing button tap

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, reactive, combine

I have a button that's connected to a `PassthroughSubject` that triggers a network load. The problem I'm having is that if the network request fails (or if pre-flight validation fails) the `PassthroughSubject` is completed:

```swift
private let createListSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

When the button is tapped, I send a new event to this subject via `send(())`.

```swift
// Later on, in some function I set up the subject
    private func setupCreateListSubject() {
        self.createListSubject
            .combineLatest(self.$listName, self.$selectedClients)
            .tryMap { [weak self] (_, listName, selectedClients) -> (String, [String]) in
                let clients = Array(selectedClients)
                try self?.validate(listName: listName, selectedClients: clients)
                return (listName, clients)
            }
            .flatMap { [clientListCreator] (listName, selectedClients) -> AnyPublisher<Result<ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Error> in
                return clientListCreator.createClientList(listName: listName, listMemberIds: selectedClients)
            }
            .catch { error  in
                return Future<Result<ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Error> { // <-- One of the problems is that Future completes after 1 event
                    $0(.success(.failure(error)))
                }
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self?.errorAlertContext = AlertContext(title: error.localizedDescription)
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self?.errorAlertContext = AlertContext(title: error.localizedDescription)
                case .success:
                    self?.errorAlertContext = nil
                }
            }).store(in: &self.disposeBag)
    }
```

There are two problems:

- When validation fails in the `tryMap`, the `catch` is invoked
- When the API call fails, the same as above happens.

I can fix both of these problems with a `replaceError` but what I want is to transform the publisher's error into a success with a `Result` error *and* for the `createListSubject` to not receive any completion events (because the user will still want to tap that button in the future.

What's the Combine way to do this?
I think what I want is something similar to `replaceError()` but that received the old error and returns a successful result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is to wrap it in a `flatMap`, so you could handle each value by producing a new publisher with the output of `Result<..., Error>` and Failure of `Never`:

```
createListSubject
   .combineLatest(self.$listName, self.$selectedClients)
   .flatMap { [weak self] (_, listName, selectedClients) -> AnyPublisher<Result< ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Never> in
        
      Just(())
      .tryMap { 
         try self?.validate(listName: listName, selectedClients: selectedClients)
      }
      .flatMap {
         // I'm assuming this returns AnyPublisher<Result<ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Error>
         clientListCreator.createClientList(listName: listName, listMemberIds: selectedClients)
      }
      .catch { err -> AnyPublisher<Result<ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Never>
         Just(.failure(err))
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
   .sink (...)
   .store(in: &self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you didn't post any code that completes `createListSubject`. You construct new publishers downstream of `createListSubject`, and those downstream publishers can fail.

You are on the right track with your `catch` block. Your `catch` block replaces the upstream failure with the output of a new publisher. The problem is that your new publisher is a `Future`, which only publishes one output and then completes.

What we want to do is send that output, and then **append the whole pipeline again**, like this:

```
        .catch {
            Just(.failure($0))
                .append(theWholePipelineAgain())
        }
```

That means we need to split up `setupCreateListSubject` into two parts. One part returns the pipeline (up to and including the `catch`), and the other part just calls `sink` on the pipeline.

Because we use `catch` to turn upstream failures into normal outputs, we can use `Never` as the `Failure` type of the pipeline. Here's the function that creates the pipeline:

```
private func createListPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Result<ClientListMembersDisplayable, Error>, Never> {
    createListSubject
        .combineLatest(
            $listName,
            // Here I'm using .map to turn Set<String> into [String] so I don't have to do it in tryMap later.
            $selectedClients
                .map { Array($0) }
        )
        .tryMap { [weak self] (_, listName, selectedClients) in
            // Here I'm creating a tuple and then returning just its .1 element, to let Swift
            // infer the return type.
            (
                try self?.validate(listName: listName, selectedClients: selectedClients),
                (listName, selectedClients)
            ).1
        }
        .flatMap { [clientListCreator] in
            clientListCreator.createClientList(listName: $0, listMemberIds: $1)
        }
        .catch { [weak self] in
            Just(.failure($0))
                .append(
                    // THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
                    self?.createListPublisher().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                        ?? Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
                )
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

And here is the function that subscribes to the pipeline:

```
private func subscribeToCreateListPublisher() {
    createListPublisher()
        .sink { [weak self] in
            switch $0 {
            case .failure(let failure):
                self?.errorAlertContext = AlertContext(title: failure.localizedDescription)
            case .success(_):
                self?.errorAlertContext = nil
            }
        }
        .store(in: &disposeBag)
}
```

Since the pipeline doesn't complete, and has a `Failure` type of `Never`, we no longer need to give a `receiveCompletion:` block to `sink`.